# Element not found for Name

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to find an element but I receive error element not found
My code:

```
    Dim bot As WebDriver
    
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Get "http://..."
    bot.FindElementByName("userName").SendKeys "text"
    bot.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys "text"
    bot.FindElementByClass("ButtonLast").Click
    
    bot.FindElementByName("searchField").SendKeys "text"
    
    Stop
```

HTML:

```html
<input
    class="SearchRoundCorner"
    onblur="searchFieldInnerTxt(this);"
    onfocus="searchFieldInnerTxt(this);"
    style="width: 150px; padding-left: 20px; color: rgb(128, 128, 128);"
    type="text"
    name="searchField"
    value="search"
    title=""
    onkeypress="if ((window.event &amp;&amp;  window.event.keyCode == 13)|| event.which==13){ document.ListView.pageNo.value=1;document.ListView.saveSelection.value = 0;submitForm(document.ListView);return false; }"
/>
```

It works well until I get to that line-bot.FindElementByName("searchField").SendKeys "text"

Error:

```
Error message:Run-Time Error 7 NoSuchElementError Element not found for name=searchfield
```

Comment: Edit your question with the URL, full page source code and pic please.

Comment: Is search button in your dom, or you need to wait some time?..

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to send a *character sequence* to the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByName*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByName("searchField").SendKeys "text"
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByCss("input.SearchRoundCorner[name='searchField'][value='search']").SendKeys "text"
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath*:

  ```
  bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@class='SearchRoundCorner' and @name='searchField'][@value='search']").SendKeys "text"
  ```